# How is the request.auth payload passed into realtime database's rules?

Tags: firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am setting my auth rules in my realtime database (in firebase) but my understanding is weak in how it works despite reading the documentation.

I have authentication set up in firebase as well as firebase functions.

The specific rule that I am struggling with is confirming the user accessing the part in the database:

```
    "$uid":{
      ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
      ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
    },
```

Simply, is the path equal to the auth id?

I have the proper auth token coming to the backend as a header, and it is being retrieved using a middleware:

```
  const idToken = req.headers.authorization.split("Bearer ")[1];
  await adminApp
    .auth()
    .verifyIdToken(idToken)
    .then((decodedIdToken) => {
      req.auth = decodedIdToken;
      next();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(403).send(`Unauthorized ${error.message}`);
    });
```

When I console `req.auth` before making the request in the function, it comes back with the full data:

```
 {
 name: 'Fake user',
 iss: '---',
 aud: '---',
 auth_time: 1669298408,
 user_id: '---',
 sub: '---',
 iat: 1669342950,
 exp: 1669346550,
 email: '---',
 email_verified: true,
 firebase: { identities: { email: [Array] }, sign_in_provider: 'password' },
 uid: '---'
}
```

(obviously censored out here)

using this function:

```
  console.log("GET ALL", req.auth);

  const { uid } = req.auth;

  get(child(dbRef, `${uid}/workouts`))
    .then((snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        return snapshot.val();
      } else {
        console.log("No workouts available");
        return null;
      }
    })
```

I know it has to do with the rules above because the error logged is a `permissions denied` type. The function also works perfectly fine when i have no rules in place...

edit:

this is the sign in function I have implemented for getting the auth token...

```
export const signIn = async (email, password) => {
  try {
    await setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence);
    const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      auth,
      email,
      password
    );

    const user = userCredential.user;
    const token = await user.getIdToken(true);
    return { user, token };
  } catch (error) {
    return { error: error.message };
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`decodedIdToken.uid` is indeed the same ID as in those security rules. However, the security rules are bypassed entirely when accessed via one of the Admin SDKs anyway.

Additionally, I would recommend taking a look at the sample express middleware function: [`validateFirebaseIdToken()`](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/490ea0b31400b4f925cb42e20eeae18f18742e88/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js#L26-L71) (as your version will throw an uncaught exception when the authorization header is not present)

Comment: Are you saying that because I am retrieving the auth payload via the admin SDK, it's not allowing the proper process of using the database rules, and that retrieving that payload through normal means would allow proper verification?

Comment: @KaseyKaufmann If you directly access the database from a client's device (phone/laptop/etc), they need to pass all the security rules you have defined to read/write to it. However, if you are accessing the database using an Admin SDK, the SDK is authorised as an administrator and can read/write any data in the database, regardless of the rules you have configured. If you wanted to access the database, but have to abide by the security rules, you need to [override that](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#authenticate-with-limited-privileges).

Comment: I don't understand what the proper way is to create and pass the firebase rules then when setting up authentication. I have only found a way to access the auth payload in the functions using the Admin SDK for the Authorization Bearer. But using the Admin SDK does not go through the proper channels to reach the database. So how is one supposed to pass in the auth payload to access the database using proper authentication?

Comment: @KaseyKaufmann When using client SDKs, you simply call the appropriate login method first, and then all subsequent requests made from that session will be authenticated as that user - you don't have to do anything special unless you are programming for something like an Arduino. For your express backend, you validate the token provided by your client-side code with the linked middleware function, and then make requests to the database in whatever way you need on behalf of that user. Because you are in total control of the backend, they can only make requests that you code into your backend.

Comment: That is actually exactly what I do already. The problem still persists though. I've added the sign in function i have implemented to my post.